# Salesforce query to get task's comment

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to get the Comments from Salesforce tasks through a SOQL query like:

```
SELECT Id, Comments from Tasks
```

but it says "Comments" is not an existing field. 
What should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field name of the Comments is "Description".

Change the query as below it will work.

"SELECT Id, Description from Task"

Regards,

Naveen

Software Engineer

http://www.autorabit.com